# DiagrammeR: How to add labels beside arrows?

Tags: r, graph, flowchart, diagrammer

I would like to create a flowchart with the `DiagrammeR` package in `R`. The graphic should look as in the following example, but I would like to add some labels above the arrows.

Consider the following reproducible example in `R`:

```
library("DiagrammeR")

# Create a node data frame (ndf)
ndf <- create_node_df(n = 4,
                      shape = c("rectangle"))

# Create an edge data frame (edf)
edf <- create_edge_df(from = c(1, 2, 3, 3),
                      to = c(4, 3, 1, 4),
                      rel = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))

# Create a graph with the ndf and edf
graph <- create_graph(nodes_df = ndf,
                      edges_df = edf)

# Create a PDF file for the graph (`graph.pdf`)
graph %>%
  export_graph(file_name = "graph.pdf",
               title = "Simple Graph")
```

With this code, I can create the following graph:

[image]

Above the 4 arrows of the graph I would like to add the labels a, b, c and d. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find anything about that in the documentation. It seems like I am doing something wrong with the `rel` argument in within the function `create_edge_df`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DiagrammeR: How to add labels beside arrows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522950/diagrammer-how-to-add-labels-beside-arrows)

Comment: @tbradley Thanks for the hint. For some reason the question was created again, after I edited it. I deleted the other question.

Comment: @tbradley I am getting a page not found error with your link. Does it work for you ?

Comment: @steveb That's because I deleted the other post (seems like I accidently posted the same question twice).

Comment: @JoachimSchork Ok, I see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you add `label = my_vector_of_labels` into the definition of create_edges:

```
# Create an edge data frame (edf) using diagrammer v 0.9.2
edf <- create_edge_df(from = c(1, 2, 3, 3),
                  to = c(4, 3, 1, 4),
                  rel = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                  label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
```

Comment: Using *DiagrammeR_0.9.2*, `could not find function "create_edges"`, what version do you have?

Comment: @zx8754 I use version 0.9.2 as well. I just replaced `rel` by `label` in the function `create_edge_df` and that worked. Actually I also don't find the function `create_edges`, so maybe the answer should be edited.

Comment: sorry, I was using the info at the DiagrammeR website, rather than the current CRAN notes. Updated